# Tips to finding dinosaur bones

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Are dinosaur bones a random find? Or is it possible to discover them by looking out for something else?
I've been roaming the countryside but never seen any.
Any hints or tips would be appreciated - but no spoilers!
I don't want to know where they actually are, just if there is a way to find them without walking accidentally on top of them.

Comment: Was there another answer to my question that got deleted? I never looked at the link.

Comment: I deleted it because it did not answer your question very well. Here is the link. Just don't look at the maps because they give away the locations. https://www.ign.com/wikis/red-dead-redemption-2/Dinosaur_Bones#Roanoke_Ridge.2C_New_Hanover_Dinosaur_Bone_Locations

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I worry that looking at it may give away the locations. Can I click and get an idea of the 'helpfulness' without ruining the surprise? Please reinstate your answer - I know where to locate the stranger...obviously.

Comment: The link gives a general location like a named area on the map. The shows the map with small circles showing the location, these can easily be scrolled past without giving anything away. Then it gives links showing pictures of the exact location. You should be able to go on the website without seeing spoilers. 

I will not be bringing my answer back because it does not add anything that the other answer did not mention.

Comment: That is strange since i asked it and the answer after yours provides no hints, map or tips. While yours does. Each to their own.

Comment: Mine gave no hints or maps, I misunderstood your question and gave an answer that did not answer the question. And he essentially summarizes my answer with the first sentence. Other than that link there was nothing special about my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dinosaur bones are found in specific locations that are static and independent of what play through you play on.

Unfortunately, there is no hint, map, or tip that can easily be used to track down each of the 30 locations found in game; you will have to "[walk] accidentally on top of them."

> To get started finding Dinosaur Bones, you need to track down a Stranger.
>
> Southeast of Horseshoe Overlook you will find a woman in the middle of a pile of mud. 
>   Speak to her and you will find that she asks you to find Dinosaur Bone Locations, there 
>   are 30 of them scattered throughout the world of Red Dead Redemption 2.

[Source.](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-12-21-red-dead-redemption-2-dinosaur-bone-locations-4975)

Comment: Well that's no fun. Does dead eye show them up at least?

Comment: @alicook Yeah Deadeye will highlight the bones for you